# How to assign a custom label to lwc property in Community Experience Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, community-builder, customlabel

I need to set the Title using a custom label:[image: 1]

It only works inside salesforce, but in order to use it in Community, it needs to be assigned from Experience Builder.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I've set the configuration xml targeting both pages, and marked the property as @api.

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>LWC</description>
    <targets>
      <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
      <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default, lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="title" type="String" label="Title" default="{!$Label.Title}"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

> @api title

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a configuration file for your LWC.

```
<LightningComponentBundle
    xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>A LWC</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property
                type="String"
                name="Name"
                label="Your Label"
                />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

this label has to be @api in the js file

More info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Comment: Thanks for answering Nicolas. Sorry for the lack of info, it's my first time posting.
I've set the configuration, along with the @api in JS. The property is displayed fine inside salesforce, but it looks like the custom label is not referenced at all in Community.